# Android Studio can't find device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am using Android Studio for Windows but it doesn't show any list of devices in the "choose a running device" option.  In a Command Tool, `adb devices` also shows nothing.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried this with 2 devices, an Xperia Sola as well as a Lenovo tablet, with the same results.
- I have enabled *USB Debugging* via *Developer's Options* on each device.
- I have tried `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`, and `adb devices` still shows nothing. However, I can see the device in Windows File Explorer.
- I checked that the driver is up-to-date.

Can anyone help solve this problem?

Comment: `adb` problems, try reinstall driver)

Comment: I re-installed the driver for my xperia. Went to device manager then to my xperia device driver option. Uninstalled it. Then plugged in the usb again and tried updating the driver where i browsed the downloaded USB driver for xperia from android developer site. It says "The best driver for your device is already installed".

Comment: What operating system should you have on your computer?

Comment: One of my friend tried in win 7 and 8. He didnt face any issue, so dont think its the OS. But not sure.

Comment: yes, it's OS, when I had `windows 8` I have some issue, problems with drivers!!

Comment: if you do not want to reinstall windows install an emulator for a while

Comment: Oh, if its OS then i guess i can try re installing the windows and see how it goes.\

Comment: Well emulator seems to work but its not really that fast even after installing the updates. Got faster. And i have tried android studio on my other laptop and it didnt work there as well. And the common thing between them is that they are both windows 8. But it worked on my friend's laptop in windows 7 and 8.1 without any driver updates or anything. Does 8 and 8.1 got anything to do with it?

Comment: If you do not want to reinstall `windows 8` then you can try `IntelliJ Idea` instead of `Android Studio`. Read about it!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and info but i fixed the issue. It was basically driver issue. And as window is in generally messed up. I had uninstall the device and driver everything and re installed and updated it using the software. Though i tried updating driver separately but that didnt work then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So here is what i did

1. reinstalled the device driver
2. changed the USB computer connection from MTP to Mass storage(UMS)

And it worked.

check out this thread [Android Studio doesn't recognize my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device/29743039#29743039)