# Android Studio Not Recognizing HTC One

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to develop on an HTC One with Lollipop installed. When I am connected to my pc, I see that the current usb connection is MTP. I have read issues where MTP was causing the issue (changing to ptp will allow the device to be recognized). How exactly do I do this?

Settings -> Storage -> USB Computer Connection (3 dot menu)

This is where everyone says you can change the setting. However, on my device, I do not have the 3 dot menu to select usb computer connection. Instead, there is just a search button. Since that menu is not there, how can I change the usb computer connection? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open Settings> About> Software Information> More.
Then tap “Build number” seven times to enable Developer options. Finally you will see “You are now a developer!” message on the screen.

Comment: I already have that enabled. Here is where someone mentions MTP being an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Answer (score -1):

Reboot your pc, Press F8 when booting and then choose the option “Disable Driver Signature Enforcement.”