# what should I do so that android studio detects device

Tags: android

android studio is unable to detect my device, for testing what should I do 
my phone is Micromax A300;I have tried to install
drivers from the internet provided by Micromax but they are useless,installing them too ;its not working

Comment: Have you enabled [ADB debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#Enabling)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device <- Have you checked these options?

Comment: not to sound like 'did you turn it on?', but also make sure you have a usb cable good for synch. Not all usb cables are created equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to device manager then it may be showing the name of your phone or some unknown device click on it; go to update driver then click "browse for driver software on your computer" then click on "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer " then a list of devices will open up; search for "android" there and click on install,this will solve the problem