# Android studio: device not recongonized?

Tags: android, android-studio

Working on android studio, I have followed all the required steps to test apps on real devices:

1. Made debugging ON on the device (7 taps)
2. Declared debugable true in manifest file.
3. Installed Google USB driver from sdk manager.

But still my `device chooser` displays `nothing to show` on opting for real device.
Please help.

*System Specification are compatible with Android Studio.

*Device is Nexus 4 with android sdk 21- (lollipop).

*`minsdk` configured to android 15.

P.S.: Both the AVD and Bluestack emulator are not working on my system (Do not suggest genimotion). Therefore I only have the option for a real device.

Comment: Go to DeviceManager (in Windows) and check if your device is installed properly under Portable Devices (in Windows 10 it would be listed under Portable Devices , may be different for Win7 or 8)

Comment: have you installed driver ?

Comment: the device is properly working. i ve checked @drWisdom

Comment: your may want to take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device?lq=1

Comment: the driver is up to date, i ve checked @tony

Comment: does the OS recognise the device when you connect it via the USB cable? Can you see the files on the device from your OS?

Comment: Connect your device "as camera"

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device with Android Debugging enabled to your PC

Open Device Manager of Windows from System Properties.

Your device should appear under 'Other devices' listed as something like 'Android ADB Interface' or 'Android Phone' or similar.

Right click that and click on 'Update Driver Software...'

Select 'Browse my computer for driver software'

Select 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer'

Double-click 'Show all devices'

Press the 'Have disk' button

Browse and navigate to [wherever your SDK has been installed]\google-usb_driver and select android_winusb.inf

Select 'Android ADB Interface' from the list of device types.

Press the 'Yes' button

Press the 'Install' button

Press the 'Close' button

Now you've got the ADB driver set up correctly. Reconnect your device if it 
doesn't recognize it already.

Comment: This was a solution for me, and these step by step instructions must be followed exactly as stated - otherwise windows will ignore the drivers as they are unsigned or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Android Studio as administrator and, beside enable Developer Mode, be sure you enabled USB debug mode and checked the popup when you connected the usb (in the device).

Otherwise, check the USB cable, I have I lot of cables that don't work for debugging but they work for charging, no idea why.