# Android studio is not showing usb device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, driver

I have android studio install in desktop and laptop. Problem is that when i connect MI pad to desktop its showing usb device and i can run my android app on MI pad. But when i connect it to laptop its not showing any usb device.

There is one thing also, when i connect my mobile, its showing in desktop as well as in laptop also..

I don't know why my MI pad is not showing in laptop.

whatever it requires i did everything like enable usb debugging etc.

please somebody help me....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't recognize my device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device)

Comment: Did you enable developer options on your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the ADB Driver manualy if automatialy did't install 
[check the link how to install the Android ADB USB driver manually](http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/)

Answer (score 2):

Install the relevant drivers that are compatible with your mobile phone that will solve the issue. Your laptop seems to not have the relevant drivers that are required for the USB drive to work effectively.

Comment: enable developer mode:
        Settings > About Phone > MIUI version.
        Tap the MIUI version message until you recive a message telling you that you are a developer.

    enable usb debugging (inside the devloper menu).

    enable fastbooting (I don't know if this one is necessary).

    install the Mi PC Suite.

    Use a USB port from behind of your computer.

    allow third party's apps on your device.

Comment: enable developer mode:
        -Settings > About Phone > MIUI version.
        -Tap the MIUI version message until you recive a message telling you that you are a developer.
-enable usb debugging (inside the devloper menu).
-enable fastbooting (I don't know if this one is necessary).
-install the Mi PC Suite.
-Use a USB port from behind of your computer.
-allow third party's apps on your device.