# Unable to connect my android device to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have samsung galaxy s5 and android studio 3.2.1. I am trying to connect my device to android studio but it is not recognised by android studio. i have already turned on debugger mod

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app

Comment: Did you setep Samsung USB Device driver?

Comment: Nop... is there will be any need of drivers???

Comment: Please check this link: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

Comment: it will be installed on samsung device???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't recognize my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199660/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device)

Comment: I have already tried these steps

Comment: Have you followed ALL the steps described by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say where your issue is without more details, but here are a few tips:

1. Make sure your USB is connected to both the phone and the computer.
2. On your phone you may need to also change the setting of how the
   device is used. When plugging your phone in you may see a
   notification from Android System that says "USB charging this
   device", which you would select and change to "Transfer Files".
3. In Android Studio if you select the menu Run > Edit Configurations, and
   in the area Deployment Target Options change Target to "Open Select
   Deployment Target Dialog". Then select menu Run > Run 'app', or
   click the green triangle to run your app. A dialog should open with
   your device as an option.
4. There may also be a notification on your
   phone requiring you to approve Android Studio's access, which you
   would select "Ok" in.